# How to view size of Lambda /tmp storage size?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How is it possbile to see the used sizes of the storage that is used by a AWS Lamdba function?

For example, like this it is possibe to check if a file exists:

```
import os
os.path.isfile('/tmp/' + filename)
```

However, I need to know when when the 512 MB limit is reached.

Comment: [Walk a Directory in Python | DevDungeon](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/walk-directory-python#oswalk_total_size)

Comment: Why do you need to know "when the limit is reached"? What will you do when it hits the limit? If possible, remove files when they are no longer used.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein for debugging its good to know when the limit is reached in order to know where the problem is caused. E.g. It could also be "full" if there are no user rights. If the limit is reached it could be possible to spend time intensive effort to reduce files.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein with that code from the link its returning the following errror:   `file_size = os.stat(filename).st_size
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '0251a5afa6ac727a1e32b7d4d4aa7cf0-le64.cache-3'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the Lambda Function is just running on a container in a linux environment, we can use the OS to tell us generally how much space we have left on the temporary filesystem.

```
from subprocess import check_output
out = str(check_output(["df", '-k']))
print(out)
result = re.search(r"(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\%\s+\/tmp", out)
size, used, available, used_pct = (int(g) for g in result.groups())  

print(size, used, available, used_pct)  # 538424 440 526148 1
```

Here's what's happening here. First We use the `subprocess.check_output` function to run the command: `df -k` which displays a string about information on the disk space usage in KB. Here's a sample of that output on a lambda function:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on\n/dev/root        6127168 4978732   1132052  82% /\n/dev/vdb         1965904   45296   1904224   3% /dev\n/dev/loop0        538424     440    526148   1% /tmp\n
```

You can see that at the end of the string is there the `/tmp` partition is located. So we take the output and search it with the regex pattern: `(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\%\s+\/tmp` which separates out the relevant fields into 4 groups which we can set to their own variables that represent the `size`: total partition size (in KB), `used`: The amount of space currently being used (in KB), `available`: The amount of space still available on the partition (in KB), and `used_pct`: The percentage of the partition space that is being used.

This is a pretty simple way of getting at the space available, I would not use this if precise measurements are needed or for guessing if a new file can be written to the disk. But if you're just logging it on execution for debugging, it should be perfectly fine.